# Can't get a user's public data from instagram's api

Tags: javascript, next.js, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have been trying to implement a basic **instagram preview app** for the past whole week that is supposed to display a preview of a user's public data like username, followers, following, profile picture url  but couldn't find any solution.

I have tried alot of npm packages but they are too old and none of them is working as instagram's api and policies have changed alot over time.

I have also tried to use **instagram's official Basic display api** and **graph api** but they dont have any methods to view a user's public profile info like username, followers, following, profile picture url etc.

I can see alot of instagram downloaders online which are doing the same thing, so clearly its do-able on this day but i just can't figure out how.

Can anybody please provide a way to do this in **2023** without violating instagram's terms and policies. It would mean alot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can only get basic public information using the API that is actually used by Instagram web application.

By tracking a few network requests in the browser we can find that an url can be formed in the following way

`https://instagram.com/{username}?__a=1&__d=1`

So suppose if my username is `harshit_singh` you can send a request to

`https://instagram.com/harshit_singh?__a=1&__d=1`.

But again remember that you will only be able to fetch public information if the account is set to private.

Comment: This works only if im logged into the instagram in browser. So i can't use in my app's backend. Secondly, i have opened the hd_profile_picture_url in the browser, the image quality is not good. I have seen alot of instagram downloader apps on google which show original quality profile photos. How are they getting high quality profile photos?